# Java для миграции баз данных

Tags: java, mysql, erp

Подскажите пожалуйста технологии(фреймворки) Java которые используются для интеграции систем. К примеру перенести все данные и бизнес логику 1С на другую ERP систему. Также для миграции бд с разных версий. Должны быть какие-то технологии для этого. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для внесений изменений в структуру базы данных и миграций удобно пользоваться [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Все изменения описываются в текстовом формате и их можно сохранить в системе контроля версий.

Comment: Это поможет перенести бизнес-логику из 1С в SAP? :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это поможет с миграцией